# Cannot normally use the studio NDK Android function

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I cannot normally use the studio NDK Android function.  The NDK has been downloaded, and I have also downloaded the LLDS. configuration file, but the problem persists.

[Example of Issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrWJN.png)

Comment: Could you not past the code here? That would be helpful.

Comment: I use studio Android to write a section of the C code, but still appear this problem, the main error is:can't resolve the type and can't resolve the variable.

Comment: I understand where there is a problem, NDK into the C header files, no stdio.h. but the tangle is just beginning, the other C's head has no stdio.h. is not my NDK environment there is a problem.